# How to get rid black border around object in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I want to put red background (layer 2) on my green object (layer 1). It all looks smooth but after I save as PNG or JPG, black border appears around my green object. How do I get rid of this black border ?

**PS**. In my photoshop screenshot below, it looks like there's black border too. But in real there's no black border. Image size is 900x900 pixel. I need to use the picture for image processing later so I can't have any other color except for my red & green value.

**What I have tried but still fail** :

1. Save as PNG
2. Save for Web and Devices in PNG24
3. Save for Web and Devices in PNG2 & unchecked transparency option
4. Flatten the image before export to PNG
5. Try to change to color mode into Indexed color and then export it

→ [Here's the file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XYG3IkqtAvcWAssLBJSowAaDbbiTzEIV).

[image]

Zoom :

[image]

This picture from the photoshop window is taken with my phone. Zoomed in 1400% and the edges are still sharp.
[image]

Comment: Could you provide the file?

Comment: sure. I'll post the link to it.

Comment: @LeoNas posted.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  The image link you posted is 938 x 938px, so if the original was 900 x 900, it seems to have been resampled, and I guess that is what has messed it up by blurring the pixels. Resampling degrades images.

Comment: @BillyKerr Hi, I rechecked the file. I believe it's still 900x900. Please check [this](https://i.imgur.com/2Ovb753.jpg).

Comment: No, the PNG file you uploaded is definitely 938 x 938px - [see screenshot here](https://i.imgur.com/h9TSxhO.png)

Comment: I didn't upload PNG file, it is PSD file. A Photoshop file. Please download the file, and not save image as. Yours is definitely bigger size than mine since the outside white border is included for the sake of image viewing. The original PSD file is without the white border.

Comment: Hmmm it would seem google drive is doing something to the image and offering me a PNG preview which is 938 x 938, whereas the download link is indeed a PSD which is 900 x 900.  It has no black pixels, only red and green.  When I export from Photoshop as PNG, it works as expected and I can't replicate the problem you are having. How are you viewing the PNG? If it's in a browser, don't zoom in on the image. View it at 100%, and it looks fine.  Does your computer have any system zoom setting?  That might explain what is happening, but this is only a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded your file, and tried to save it in the five ways you mention. I can't reproduce the problem.

The black border you are experiencing must come from scaling the image.

Are you sure that the image you save is the exact same size as the original psd?

If you are sure of the dimensions, then where are you opening the resulting image?

If you open it in a web browser and zoom in, the browser will scale the image using bicubic interpolation by default, which will cause a blurred edge.

---

EDIT:

In your screenshot it is obvious that the image has been upscaled.

[image]

Your original image is aliased with jagged edges and only red and green pixels. In the screenshot there is about 30 pixels of intermediate tones for 1 original pixel. There isn't just a "black border" - the image has been upscaled using some kind of bicubic interpolation. Since you are sure that it doesn't happen in Photoshop it must happen when you upload or manipulate the image in Picasa. When and how, I can't know (maybe you are applying the image to a larger image and Picasa automatically resizes the image?). I don't understand why you want/need to do image processing in Picasa, when you have access to Photoshop though.

Comment: Hi, thanks ! I believe it is not because of scaling the image. I open my image in image viewer by the way, using Picassa. 
But what makes me 100% sure the black border is in there, after I use the image as an input for my image processing, there are more than 2 values (red - 255,0,0 and green (0,255,0) detected.

Comment: and the output from the image processing also shows the black border exactly on the edge of the image.

Comment: Isn't Picasa a web page? What sort of image processing are you talking about?

Comment: Is the black border visible if you open the exported png in Photoshop?

Comment: Have you checked the pixel dimensions of the output from your image processing? Are they the same as the original image?

Comment: Picassa by Google. You can access it online and offline (software installer). I'm using the offline version, it's something like ACD see.   
I'm doing image processing in programming. The program will not change the pixel dimension, just compute the RGB value from the image. Input size and output size will always be the same

Comment: But since there are 30 pixels per original pixel in your screenshot it can't be the same size! Please see my last edit.

Comment: Thanks, I read your updated answer. "Your original image is aliased with jagged edges", from which picture is this ? I uploaded several pictures above. Please check the last pic I took with my cellphone, there no jagged edges at all. It is on 1400% size on Photoshop. Also, I think we have some kind of misunderstanding here. I don't do image processing in Picassa. Picassa is just an image viewer that I use. You can never do image-processing programming with an image viewer. I'm doing image processing using c++ and open cv programming language.

Comment: Your original psd has "jagged" edges = "sharp" edges = _aliased_ = only two colors. Your screenshot showing the problem has "smooth" edges = _anti-aliased_ = many colors. Maybe Picasa applies _bicubic interpolation_ when you zoom in? Photoshop uses _nearest neighbor_ when zooming and shows the true pixels of the image. If the image looks correct in Photoshop, this might be a coding question and not a Photoshop question.

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of that. It shows aliased (without smoothing) on Photoshop. But after I exported, there's a smooth line (the black line that I mentioned). That is why I'm asking, I thought probably this is the problem with how I exported the file ? Maybe I exported the wrong way ? Also, I believe this is not a coding question. I know exactly the code, it's just computing the RGB value. I'll keep trying things out. I'll update when I have progress.

Comment: Please check this for me: Open the _exported png image_ (not the original) in _Photoshop_ (not Picasa) and check if the there is a black line and check if the image is still 900x900 px.

Comment: FYI: I can't replicate this issue either.

Comment: Thanks @Wolff ! the answer is posted below. It was a mistake the way I exported my image into PNG.

Comment: Good to hear you solved your issue, but too bad you didn't accept my answer - I was trying to guide you to the answer. Btw, you say in your question that you tried to just save as png. This shouldn't scale the image, so I don't really get it.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer. Thanks for nayhem_jr, original post on Reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/photoshop/comments/9hfy2t/how_to_get_rid_black_border_around_object_in/).

- Export the image using Save for Web and Devices
- Make sure the image scaling is at 100%, because unwanted color values will appear due to interpolation. I should save the image at 100% scaling. (My default was also 100%)
- Then this, Choose Quality = Nearest Neighbor (my default setting was Bicubic)

[image]

This works like a charm ! The black lines aren't there anymore.